# Android App Bundle (.aab) crashes on device

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, android-app-bundle

application does not work when I translate to aab, but it works when I run on android studio

-I did rebuild again
-I deleted the caches

I used packages

````
"dependencies": {
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "js-md5": "^0.7.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "md5": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "16.7.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
    "react-native-device-info": "git+https://github.com/nejcet/react-native-device-info.git",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-fs": "git+https://github.com/nejcet/react-native-fs.git",
    "react-native-google-analytics": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-image-gallery": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-parsed-text": "0.0.21",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-switch-pro": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-video": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-video-controls": "^2.2.3",
    "react-native-view-pdf": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-windows": "^0.57.0-rc.0",
    "react-native-windows-chromium-browser": "file:node_local_modules/react-native-windows-chromium-browser",
    "react-native-zip-archive": "file:node_local_modules/react-native-zip-archive",
    "react-navigation-transitions": "^1.0.8",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-immutable": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist-immutable": "^4.3.1",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.2",
    "redux-storage": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-storage-engine-reactnativeasyncstorage": "^1.0.5",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.15"
  },
```
````

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace of the crash by looking at the logcat: saying it "crashes" is too vague.

Comment: there is no problem at logcat everything is normal

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work" then?

Answer (score 0):

To test an app bundle locally you need to use bundletool since it's merely a publishing format used to generate the APKs you need.

Comment: You can also deploy APKs generated from the App Bundle from Studio.